# What is mean keras.Flatten()()?

Tags: python, tf.keras, keras-layer

Please tell me what it means if there are two () in Flatten as shown below. Thank you.

```py
conv_output = Dropout(0.25)(h)
    
    # classification layers
    h = Flatten()(conv_output)
    h = concatenate([h, Flatten()(aux_input)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is python related not really keras related:

by calling:

```
i = Flatten()
```

You instantiate a Flatten object.

By calling: `i(conv_output)` you call the method `__call__` of the `Flatten` class

Writing it `h = Flatten()(conv_output)` is just a shortcut because you do not care about the `i` variable. What you get in h is the return value of the `__call__` method of `Flatten` class